# C++ Cmake build with cotire and gtest - error with float.h

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest

I have a cmake build that uses gtest - everything works as expected. When I add cotire in I get the error:

`error: use of undeclared identifier 'DBL_MAX'`

Anywhere `#import <float.h>` is used

It seems to me that some setting is being fubar'd by adding cotire, but the environment variables look roughly the same

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/259e824359b7b399bc10f7aefd30b827

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: If you have both `float.h` and `gtest-internal.h`, can you try removing `float.h` and try again?

Comment: I should have been more clear - it's in the gtest codebase itself that give off these errors. Not any code we have written.

Comment: Try including `<cfloat>` instead of `<float>`. If that works, I'll explain more why in a full answer.

Comment: Are you trying to use cotire to do a single compilation unit build that includes everything in your application as well as everything in gtest?  Given that everyone has questions from your description, I think we need an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @CinderBiscuits - that change did not fix the issues, thank you for the suggestion though!

I replaced the DBL_MAX with std:numeric_limits<> and it works fine now - I am trying to figure out what is causing this misconfiguration.

Comment: @legalize - I agree - I'm short on time right now, but will try to get one together ASAP.